# VLOOKUP using pandas without repetition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. How do I obtain df3 using pd.merge or any other function?

What I tried?

`df3=df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left')`

This gives me df3 with number of rows same as df2. But, what I want is number of rows in df1 and df3 are same. df3 should look exactly as in the example provided.

df1

```
A   B
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   7
7   1
8   1
9   9
10  3
```

df2

```
A   C
1   XY
1   XY
2   XY
2   XY
2   XY
3   XY
3   XY
4   XY
4   XY
5   XY
5   XY
6   AB
6   AB
7   AB
8   AB
9   AB
9   AB
9   AB
10  MN
10  MN
```

df3

```
A   B   C
1   1   XY
2   1   XY
3   2   XY
4   2   XY
5   3   XY
6   7   AB
7   1   AB
8   1   AB
9   9   AB
10  3   MN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` to keep one instance of `(A, B)`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left').drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], ignore_index=True)
     A  B   C
0    1  1  XY
2    2  1  XY
5    3  2  XY
7    4  2  XY
9    5  3  XY
11   6  7  AB
13   7  1  AB
14   8  1  AB
15   9  9  AB
18  10  3  MN
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you want to keep one instance of `A` AND `B` but the answer is still the same with `drop_duplicates`.

Answer (score 1):

map works too

```py
# map df2.C to df1.A via df2.A
df1["C"] = df1.A.map(df2.drop_duplicates().set_index('A').C)
df1
```

[image]